# Removing a period from a several file names using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've found several related posts to this but when I try to use the code suggested I keep getting "The system cannot find the file specified".  I imagine it's some kind of path problem.  There are several folders within the "Cust" folder and each of those folders have several files and some have "." in the file name I need to remove.  Any idea what I have wrong here?

```
customer_folders_path = r"C:\Users\All\Documents\Cust"
for directname, directnames, files in os.walk(customer_folders_path):
    for file in files:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(file)
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]            
        if "." in filename_zero:
            os.rename(filename_zero, filename_zero.replace(".", ""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `os.walk` and then iterate through the files, remember that you are only iterating through file names - not the full path (which is what is needed by `os.rename` in order to function properly). You can adjust by adding the full path to the file itself, which in your case would be represented by joining `directname` and `filename_zero` together using `os.path.join`:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(directname, filename_zero), 
          os.path.join(directname, filename_zero.replace(".", "")))
```

Also, not sure if you use it elsewhere, but you could remove your `filename_split` variable and define `filename_zero` as `filename_zero = os.path.splitext(file)[0]`, which will do the same thing. You may also want to change `customer_folders_path = r"C:\Users\All\Documents\Cust"` to `customer_folders_path = "C:/Users/All/Documents/Cust"`, as the directory will be properly interpreted by Python.

**EDIT:** As intelligently pointed out by @bozdoz, when you split off the suffix, you lose the 'original' file and therefore it can't be found. Here is an example that should work in your situation:

```
import os

customer_folders_path = "C:/Users/All/Documents/Cust"
for directname, directnames, files in os.walk(customer_folders_path):
    for f in files:
        # Split the file into the filename and the extension, saving
        # as separate variables
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if "." in filename:
            # If a '.' is in the name, rename, appending the suffix
            # to the new file
            new_name = filename.replace(".", "")
            os.rename(
                os.path.join(directname, f),
                os.path.join(directname, new_name + ext))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  So I updated with your suggestions and I'm still getting the same exact error.  I've checked it several times to make sure I had all the syntax right and I do.  I must have something else wrong.

Comment: @wilbev I would then try just doing a simple print of the result of `os.path.join(directname, filename_zero)` when it triggers your condition - basically, we want to confirm that the file it is renaming does exist :)

Comment: @wilbev Ah, and I just noticed your initial directory name - try removing the `r` and changing the backslashes to front slashes (which will be properly converted to backslashes by Python). The directory itself could be causing the issue here.

Comment: Yep, I did that and it definitely print the full file path and looks accurate.  Just seems like when I try to the rename method, just says system cannot fine the file specified.  Just tried your front slashes and no help either. Strange..

Comment: Can it find the right file if you're searching for filename_zero?  Isn't that the file without the extension?

Comment: @wilbev And you did the same thing to the renamed file? Hmm, weird. I'll be back in a bit and will take another look.

Comment: @bozdoz Doh, great, great suggestion :)

Comment: I'd have put an answer, but it would have just been a remake of yours. :)

Comment: @bozdoz I'll update in a bit, but I will owe you a future +1 for that one :)

Comment: Thanks @bozdoz for catching that.  I've almost got it working now but now it's removing the period from the file extension too.  Hoping you or RocketDonkey can help me with that.

Comment: @wilbev Make sure that you replace the extension after you do the replace. Typing on a phone now, but will update with more detail in a bit :)

Comment: @wilbev Dropped in an update - happy to tweak if it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the original filename as the first parameter to os.rename and handle the case where the filename didn't have a period in the first place. How about:

```
customer_folders_path = r"C:\Users\All\Documents\Cust"
for directname, directnames, files in os.walk(customer_folders_path):
    for fn in files:
        if '.' in fn:
            fullname = os.path.join(directname, fn)
            os.rename(fullname, os.path.splitext(fullname)[0])
```